# SQL Server - from two rows, one column to one row, two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
if object_id( 'tempdb.dbo.#ctp', 'u' ) is not null
  drop table #ctp ;
create table #ctp( id int, mastername varchar( 16 ) ) ;
insert into #ctp values( 1, 'Big Boy' ) ;

if object_id( 'tempdb.dbo.#client', 'u' ) is not null
  drop table #client ;
create table #client( id int, name varchar(16 ), type int ) ;
insert into #client values( 1, 'ABC', 5 ) ;
insert into #client values( 2, 'XYZ', 6 ) ;

if object_id( 'tempdb.dbo.#ctpclient', 'u' ) is not null
  drop table #ctpclient ;
create table #ctpclient( id int, ctpfk int, clientfk int ) ;
insert into #ctpclient values( 1, 1, 1 ) ;
insert into #ctpclient values( 2, 1, 2 ) ;

select   tp.mastername
       , c.name
       , c.type
       , cc.ctpfk
       , cc.clientfk
from     #ctp tp
join     #ctpclient cc
  on     tp.id = cc.ctpfk
join     #client c
  on     c.id = cc.clientfk 
  ;
```

current output

```
mastername|name|type
Big Boy|ABC|5
Big Boy|XYZ|6
```

Instead of two rows of output, I would like the output to be as follows:

```
mastername|nameone|nametwo
Big Boy   | ABC   | XYZ
```

What is the optimal way to do this given that I have a many to many table such as #ctpclient?

Comment: Read about [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have 2 rows you can use a crosstab (aka conditional aggregation). It would look something like this.

```
with SortedValues as
(
    select tp.mastername
        , c.name
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by mastername order by clientfk) as RowNum
    from #ctp tp
    join #ctpclient cc on tp.id = cc.ctpfk
    join #client c on c.id = cc.clientfk
)

select mastername
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 1 then name end) as NameOne
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 2 then name end) as NameTwo
from SortedValues
group by mastername
```

If you have a varying numbers you can still accomplish but it is bit more complex.

Comment: Of course, this was a very simplified example.  What is there works but instead of a single group by I actually have about 20 other character columns that would need to be grouped.  Is there an alternative technique to this issue?  I was thinking of some type of subqury in the SELECT statement but really not sure best way to do this...

Comment: Why can't you just add the extra columns and the group by? No matter what approach you take you are going to have to type all the column names at some point.